# Installing Orion Context Broker

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, fiware, fiware-orion

I have been trying to install the Orion Context Broker in Ubuntu 16.04, for this I have tried to build the source of the broker, but without success. Can someone tell me the best way? How do I configure Fiware packages for use with apt-get?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide detail about the problem you have trying to build Orion in Ubuntu? For instance, the error you get at compiling time, if any. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install Orion is using Docker. (https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/).

Docker and docker-compose. You install Orion and Mongodb together, in a quick time. (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/tree/master/docker)

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the broker from sources in a VM with Ubuntu 16.04.
Luckily I saved the steps :)

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install git

cd
mkdir git
cd git
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion.git
cd fiware-orion

#
# To compile the broker, install the following packages:
#
sudo aptitude install cmake
sudo aptitude install g++
sudo aptitude install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo aptitude install uuid-dev
sudo aptitude install libgnutls-dev
sudo aptitude install libgcrypt-dev
sudo aptitude install scons
sudo aptitude install libboost-dev
sudo aptitude install libboost-regex-dev
sudo aptitude install libboost-thread-dev
sudo aptitude install libboost-filesystem-dev

#
# Install MHD, from source
#
sudo mkdir /opt/libmicrohttpd
sudo chown <user>:<group> /opt/libmicrohttpd
cd /opt/libmicrohttpd
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libmicrohttpd/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48.tar.gz
tar xvf libmicrohttpd-0.9.48.tar.gz
cd libmicrohttpd-0.9.48
./configure --disable-messages --disable-postprocessor --disable-dauth
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig


#
# Install mongo client, from source
#
sudo mkdir /opt/mongodb
sudo chown <user>:<group> /opt/mongodb
cd /opt/mongodb
wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/legacy-1.1.2.tar.gz
tar xfvz legacy-1.1.2.tar.gz
cd mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2
sudo scons install --prefix=/usr/local --disable-warnings-as-errors


#
# Install rapidjson, from source
#
sudo mkdir /opt/rapidjson
sudo chown <user>:<group> /opt/rapidjson
cd /opt/rapidjson
wget https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/archive/v1.0.2.tar.gz
tar xfvz v1.0.2.tar.gz
sudo mv rapidjson-1.0.2/include/rapidjson/ /usr/local/include

#
# Ready to compile the broker
# However, to install in privileged directories, we need to prepare a little first:
#
sudo touch /usr/bin/contextBroker
sudo touch /etc/default/contextBroker
sudo mkdir /etc/init.d/contextBroker
sudo chown <user>:<group> /usr/bin/contextBroker
sudo chown <user>:<group> /etc/default/contextBroker
sudo chown <user>:<group> /etc/init.d/contextBroker


#
# Now let's compile and install
#
cd ~/git/fiware-orion
make di

#
# Test
#
# You need two terminals for this:
# - One xterm to start the broker in (foreground)
# - One xterm to send a command to the broker, and see the result:
#
# (In xterm 1): contextBroker -fg
# (In xterm 2): curl localhost:1026/version
#
# The output should be similar to this:
#
# {
#   "orion" : {
#     "version" : "1.10.0-next",
#     "uptime" : "0 d, 0 h, 0 m, 6 s",
#     "git_hash" : "97623c4c001d56b5458c9ecc5b191ecb812ce257",
#     "compile_time" : "nodate",
#     "compiled_by" : "ken",
#     "compiled_in" : "localhost",
#     "release_date" : "nodate",
#     "doc" : "https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master/"
#   }
# }
#
```

Comment: When I try this command "/usr/bin/contextBroker chown <user>:<group> /etc/default/contextBroker" i get "/usr/bin/contextBroker: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread-mt.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
" as output. And i've followed all of your steps.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure you followed all the steps?

Comment: One of the steps is:
`sudo aptitude install libboost-thread-dev`
which installs ... wait ... mt (multi-threading) ... check the toplevel CMakeLists.txt with your distro (Ubuntu 16.04, right?) to see if you need BOOST or BOOST_MT.  If Ubuntu 16.04, it should **not** be MT ...

Comment: There was a typo in my text ...
 "/usr/bin/contextBroker chown <user>:<group> /etc/default/contextBroker", doesn't make much sense, does it? :)
Typo fixed.